# Padé approximant for a function $ f(x) $ always valid?

Tags: approximation-theory

Is there any function $f(x)$ which can not be approximated by a Padé rational approximant?

$$f(x) \approx \frac{a_0+a_1 x+ \ldots +a_nx^n}{b_0+b_1 x+ \ldots +b_m x^m} $$

What happens with $f(x)= \tan(x)$ or $f(x)=\log^{a}(x)$

Comment: There are conditions, the simplest being that you cannot guarantee approximation unless the function is continuous on a closed bounded interval. As you noticed, logarithm fails at $\infty.$ For that purpose, you could just ask about $\sqrt x.$ Again, you can do $\tan x$ on $- \pi / 4 \leq x \leq \pi / 4.$

Comment: Also take a look at [CORDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC) for practical ways of computing several functions.

Comment: Do you know how to compute Pade approximation?

Answer (score 0):

Here is Padé approximation for $\tan(x)$

$$ \tan(x)\approx \frac{-{\frac {1}{135135}}\,{x}^{7}+{\frac {2}{715}}\,{x}^{5}-{
\frac {5}{39}}\,{x}^{3}+x }{  1-{\frac {6}{13}}\,{x}^{2}+{
\frac {10}{429}}\,{x}^{4}-{\frac {4}{19305}}\,{x}^{6}  } . $$